# How to get user input and pass it as an argument in function inside classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am new to python and I am trying to find a efficient way to get user input for the following and pass them as arguments in function while using classes. I am new to oops and I am finding it hard to get user input from user while implementing classes and objects

Can someone help me how do I efficiently get user input for the following in the code below :
**remote
upload_local_path
download_local**

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, hostname, user, password):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def connect_paramiko(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(self.hostname, port=22, username=self.user, password=self.password)
        print("connected successfully")
       
        return ssh
    

    def uploadtoRemote(self,myhost,myusername,mypassword,remote_path, upload_local_path):
                ssh = self.connect_paramiko()
                sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
                files = os.listdir(upload_local_path)
                for file in files:
                        sftp.put(os.path.join(upload_local_path, file), remote_path + "/" + file)
                sftp.close()
           




    def downloadtoLocal(self,remote,download_local):
       '''getting the file from remote to local host'''
       ssh = self.connect_paramiko()
       sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
       self.inbound_files = sftp.listdir(remote)
       for ele in self.inbound_files:
       sftp.get(remote, download_local)
       sftp.close()
       ssh.close()

      
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    m1=Myclass("abc.com","user", "user")
    remote="abc.com"
    upload_local_path="/abc/book/lib"
    download_local="/abc/book/efg"
    m1.uploadtoRemote("abc.com","user", "user",upload_local_path)
    m1.downloadtoLocal(remote,download_local) '''
```

Comment: Do you know how to get input from the user, using the `input` function?  That's how you do it.  Instead of hardcoding the strings in your main code, you give the user a prompt so they know what to enter, and you read it with `input`.  This has nothing to do with OOP.  Your object does not need to know where the data came from.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your response. Should I get the input while I am calling function? that is remote = input("enter remote") or should I get it outside the function and declare them globally under the class?

Comment: No, look at what you're already doing.  You are setting up constant values for those variables, then passing them into the class method.  Nothing about that has to change, nor does the class have to change.  You just read those values from `input` instead of hard-coding the strings.  I'm GUESSING you will also want to ask for a username and password instead of hardcoding, but that depends on your requirement.

Comment: @TimRoberts I need help is it the same way when I am passing the variables and creating an instance I want to get input for host user and password like you said. But I created those variables in __init__. is there another way to take input in the init function itself?

Comment: But you're creating them in `Myclass.__init__` from the values that are passed, from the main code, like I did below.  As an overly general rule, don't take user input in your classes.  That forces the user to type something every time you create a new object.  Let the CALLER decide where the data comes from.  The class just USES the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    remote=input("Enter the remote system name: ")
    user=input("Enter your username: ")
    passwd=input("Enter the password (insecure): ")
    upload_local_path=input("Enter the local upload path: ")
    download_local=input("Enter the local download path: ")
    m1=Myclass(remote, user, passwd)
    m1.uploadtoRemote(remote, user, passwd,upload_local_path)
    m1.downloadtoLocal(remote,download_local)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I overthought the solution